# Lagrange Multipliers; two inequalities.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I want to min/max $f(x,y,z)$ under the constraint $c_2 \leq g(x,y,z) \leq c_1$. I would first check $\nabla f = 0$ and find critical points in $c_2 \leq g(x,y,z) \leq c_1$. Afterwards, I do the boundary with Lagrange Multipliers.

Is this the correct setup? Let $g(x,y,z) = c_1$ and $g(x,y,z) = c_2$

$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g + \mu \nabla g$

s.t

$g = c_1$

$g = c_2$

I tried it and I got a contradiction.

Comment: You are mixing two things here. You are looking for the extremum of $f(x,y,z)$ and all of a sudden you have constraints on a function $g(x,y,z)$. I think you should write $$g(x,y,z) \leq f(x,y,z) \leq h(x,y,z) $$

Then the equation for a constraint extremum becomes:
$$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g + \mu \nabla h $$

with $g(x,y,z)=c_1$ and $h(x,y,z)=c_2$

Comment: @michielm : I think OP knows what he wants to do, he just doesn't know how to do it, and it seems like a plausible hypothesis. Unless he is asking the wrong question.

Comment: It seems odd that you would have $g=c_1$ and $g=c_2$ simultaneously. Don't you want to consider those as two disjoint cases?

Comment: I could, but then I would get two different extremes on $A$.

Comment: I am skeptical. My interpretation is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my interpretation, based on what you've explained:

Consider a simple situation. $g(x,y,z)=z$. Then $z$ is allowed to vary from $z=c_1$ to $z=c_2$. We look for how $f$ varies in these layers of $(x,y,z)$ (such that $c_1\le z\le c_2$). To check for critical points on the interior, that is, for $c_1<z<c_2$, we simply check for where $\nabla f=0$. To check for critical points on the boundaries, we use the method of lagrange multipliers, so that $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$. These vectors will be checked for parallelness at the two boundaries *separately*. We *cannot* be at both boundaries simultaneuously. So, we check if this is possible for $z=c_1$, then, we check if it is possible at $c_2$.

In my simple example, your method would immediately get a contradiction, since then 
$$c_1=z=c_2,$$
contradiction. This may be the source of your contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how advanced your level of mathematics is, but the general problem 
$$
\min_{(x,y,z) \in A}  f(x,y,z), \quad A = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \, | \, c_1 \le g(x,y,z) \le c_2 \}
$$
where say, $f, g$ are differentiable "a lot" (let's be friendly) is actually very hard (feasible, the techniques are developed, but it's not for a beginner undergraduate student). I suspect that you formulated homework in a weird way and it got out this way. I am saying it is very hard because this is exactly what the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker multipliers deal with, and these multipliers are usually met in an optimization course at an advanced level of calculus/analysis. I suggest you clarify what was your original problem, perhaps it would make things easier to answer.

Hope that helps,

Comment: How does one apply the KKT to this problem then?

Comment: @sizz : It's painful. Very painful computations. See here for an example of the use of the KKT techniques. http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m340/kkt2.pdf

Comment: Essentially the idea is to replace the inequality by an equality with an extra variable but the fact that you have intervals of values and not equations makes it harder to develop the theory. I can't do it here, there are too many details.

If you didn't have such a problem as homework but were simply interested in knowing if such a problem was solvable and if we had techniques to do it, then my answer is yes, but unless you can understand (at least vaguely) what's on the wikipedia page of Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions, don't think about it. If you're still curious, I can find a reference.